# access array through .data variable or through register

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I have an array and I'm loading the base address of this array into the %esi register. I can access the first element in the array for instance like this: `pushl 0(%esi)`, the second like this: `pushl 4(%esi)`, and so on. But I get an segmentation fault if I'm replacing the number before `(%esi)` with a variable from the .data section:

```
.data
array: .long 1,2,3,4,5
k: .long 4
out: .string "out: %d\n"

.globl main
main:

  #load array-baseaddress into %esi
  leal  array, %esi

  # Will print 1
  pushl 0(%esi)
  pushl $out
  call printf

  # Will print 2
  pushl 4(%esi)
  pushl $out
  call printf

  # Will result in segmentation fault
  pushl k(%esi)
  pushl $out
  call printf

  call exit
```

Can somebody explain to me why this is not working and if it's possible to access an element of an array in such a manner?

Comment: Have you actually initialized `esi` anywhere?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was in a hurry and forgot to add the line. It's corrected now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have this at the top of your function *main*:

```
main:
  # Will print 1
  pushl 0(%esi)
  pushl $out
  call printf
```

The first issue is that you use indexed addressing (with displacement) with the value in *ESI* as the address. So you have the equivalent of the value at memory address *ESI+0* . The problem is that you don't initialize *ESI* . You should be initializing it with the address of *array* . So change the code to:

```
main:
  mov $array, %esi    /* initialize ESI with address of array. */

  # Will print 1
  pushl 0(%esi)
  pushl $out
  call printf
```

In the last section of code you do:

```
# Will result in segmentation fault
pushl k(%esi)
pushl $out
call printf
```

You are looking to use the value in variable *k* as a displacement when you do `k(%esi)` . Unfortunately indexed addressing (with displacement) only supports a displacement as a constant. In your case `k(%esi)` is taking the address of *k* and adding it to *ESI* and pushing the value at that address on the stack. That isn't what you want. You can't do this in one operation. You'll have to retrieve the value in variable *k* and put it in a free register and then use that register to compute the address using based indexed addressing mode. You can do that with code like this:

```
movl   k, %eax         /* move 32-bit value in k to temporary register */
pushl  (%esi, %eax)    /* Push 32-bit value @ memory location %esi+%eax to stack */
pushl $out
call printf
```

The output would look like:

```
out: 1
out: 2
out: 2
```

From your code it is uncertain if *k* was holding an element number within the array or if it was just a byte offset in the array. If you were looking to access the *k*th element in the array (0 based) then you need to use a scaling factor on the based indexed addressing mode like this:

```
movl   k, %eax         /* move 32-bit value in k to temporary register */
pushl  (%esi, %eax, 4) /* Push 32-bit value @ memory location %esi+(%eax*4) to stack */
pushl $out
call printf
```

This would print out the 4th element (0 based) in *array* or the value `5` in your case. The output would look like:

```
out: 1
out: 2
out: 5
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to achieve this using based indexed addressing mode but I didn't know what register to use as the base register.

Comment: This [addressing mode list](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/V22.0201-002/addressing_modes.pdf) applies to 32 bit code (doesn't apply to 16-bit code which is more limited)